# problem in installing the fingerprint-aio plugin?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic3, cordova-plugins

What is suitable version for ionic 3 and cordova android platform 6.4.0 of  fingerprint-aio

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio
>   install --save @ionic-native/fingerprint-aio

Comment: Hi, did you get it working ?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin requires a minimum Android SDK version of 23